Вычисление среднего в скользящем окне дает нули
window = []
window_sum = 0
for i in range (len(numbers_list)):
    try:
        window [numbers_list[i] : numbers_list[i + window_size] :]
    except:
        window [numbers_list[i]::]
    for q in range (len(window)):
        window_sum += window[q]
    temp_result = window_sum/window_size
    result.append (temp_result)
print(result)


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример

window [numbers_list[i] : numbers_list[i + window_size] :] и window [numbers_list[i]::] - эти операции ничего не делают. Вам нужно в window присвоить новый список, а то что вы пытаетесь из пустого списка window что-то получить - ничего не дает.

Опишите словами в вопросе какую задачу вы решаете.

как тогда? просто равно ставить - ошибку выдаёт

В ответе уже написал

Операции window [numbers_list[i] : numbers_list[i + window_size] :] и window [numbers_list[i]::] никак window не изменяют. window у вас всегда остается пустым списком, которым вы его изначально инициализировали. Сумма элементов пустого списка - ноль.
Вам нужно взять сечение от number_list и записать (присвоить) в переменную window:
window = numbers_list[i: i + window_size]

try-except тут не нужно, ошибки при выходе второго индекса за границы списка не будет, просто сечение будет максимум до конца списка.
В исправленном виде более-менее полный пример будет таким:
import random

numbers_list = [random.randint(0, 100) for _ in range(10)]
print(numbers_list)

result = []
window_size = 5

for i in range (len(numbers_list)):
    window = numbers_list[i: i + window_size]

    window_sum = 0  # нужно обнулять сумму
    for q in range (len(window)):
        window_sum += window[q]
        
    temp_result = window_sum/window_size
    result.append (temp_result)
print(result)

Обратите внимание, что перед суммированием элементов окна нужно сумму обнулить, иначе это будет сумма всех предыдущих окон, и среднее будет неправильным.
Ну и сумму можно просто функцией sum считать:
for i in range(len(numbers_list)):
    window = numbers_list[i: i + window_size]
    window_sum = sum(window)
    average = window_sum/window_size
    result.append(average)

